# How to work with dataframe values that are lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains lists of values in the columns like this:
[image]

I would like to extract all the rows that contain the value 'adhd'. code that I used:

```
df[df["Label"] == "adhd"]
```

But it returns to me an empty dataframe with just the column names. Is it because my data is in list format? is there any way to process this so that I can drop rows, view rows and work with them. I would prefer to keep them as list since many rows has multiple values like ["adhd","depression"].

Comment: please post a dataframe as example in form of text instead of images..

Comment: try `df[df["Label"] == ["adhd"]]`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep them in lists you can perform operations like the ones you stated like this:

```py
df[df['label'].apply(lambda x: x ==['adhd'])]  # keep people that only have ADHD 
df[df['label'].apply(lambda x: 'adhd' in x)]  # keep all people that have ADHD
```

I would suggest however to one-hot encode your data, i.e. keep one column per label (e.g. one column for ADHD that takes the value 1 if person has ADHD, otherwise 0).

The simplest way to do this, I think is:

```py
df['label'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Then you can process your data more easily.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But how can I drop the rows containing 'adhd' value?

Comment: If you can select the values you can also drop them: `df = df[~df['label'].apply(lambda x: x ==['adhd'])]`

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
df[df['Label'].apply(lambda x: 'adhd' in x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution without apply method:

generated example dataframe:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=[[str(i)] for i in range(0,10000,1000)],another_data=range(0,100000,10000)))

example_df

    data    another_data
0   [0] 0
1   [1000]  10000
2   [2000]  20000
3   [3000]  30000
4   [4000]  40000
5   [5000]  50000
6   [6000]  60000
7   [7000]  70000
8   [8000]  80000
9   [9000]  90000
```

fix the current dataframe:

```
example_df = example_df.explode('data')

>>>
    data    another_data
0   0   0
1   1000    10000
2   2000    20000
3   3000    30000
4   4000    40000
5   5000    50000
6   6000    60000
7   7000    70000
8   8000    80000
9   9000    90000
```

get filtered:

```
example_df[example_df['data'] == '1000']

>>>
    data    another_data
1   1000    10000
```

**UPDATE**

to drop the unwanted rows that have the wanted value:

```
example_df = example_df[example_df['data'] !='1000']
example_df 

>>>
    data    another_data
0   0   0
2   2000    20000
3   3000    30000
4   4000    40000
5   5000    50000
6   6000    60000
7   7000    70000
8   8000    80000
9   9000    90000
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello i hope i'll help you. I discover this way a few weeks ago.

Pandas treath dictionaries, list, tuples, etc... like objects (In newer version of pandas also can be called string Dtype)

With that in mind you can do this

```
example_df = [*([['foo']] * 79)]
example_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Label': [*example_df, ['Love']],
  'Post': [*example_df, ['Another Value']]
})
example_df[
  example_df.Label.str.contains('Love', regex = False)
]
```

This was the result

[image]

Also you can work with position in array with [str accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) (This pandas method brings a great functions for strings Dtypes)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`df = df[df["Label"].astype(str).str.contains("Label")]`